# Heat-map Will Not update

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to `D3.js`, and having some issues with getting a heat map to update.I can build the initial heat-map no problem, but when I use the second heat map, I cannot get it to update with new data.

If I change the line of code

```
.style('fill',function(d) { return myColor(d.Class1)} )
```

to

```
.style('fill','grey')
```

the heat-map turns grey - so I know something is preventing me from binding the data to the squares, but I cannot figure out what.

```
d3.interval(function(){ updateData();}, 10000)

function updateData(){

  //Read the data
  d3.csv("new_data.csv", function(data) {

      svg.selectAll('rect').data(data).transition()
          .duration(0)
          .style('fill',function(d) { return myColor(d.Class1)} )
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody else has this problem, it was an order/syntax error.

```
.duration(0)
```

has to come after

```
.style('fill',function(d) { return myColor(d.Class1)} )
```